# Async.series doesn't work with fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

At first step I wanna load file into variable named 'file' and then, at second step, 
do response.write(file)
To achieve this i use async.series, but something wrong with my code.
Here is the code i use to launch server :

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require('fs'),
    async = require('./js/async.js');

var onRequest = function(request,response) {
  response.writeHead(200,{ "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8" });

  var file;            // 'file' declared

  var main = function(callback) {
    fs.readFile('.\\html\\admin.html','utf-8',function(err,data) {
      file = data;     // 'file' is given content of admin.html
      console.log('2 >> ' + typeof file);
    });
    callback(null);
  }

  console.log('1 >> ' + typeof file);

  async.series([
    main                       
  ], function() {      // At this point 'file' is still undefined, that's odd
    response.end();    // 'cause it's a callback and should be fired after 'main'
    console.log('3 >> ' + typeof file);
  });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80);
```

The trouble is in the subject - async.series doesn't work as i expect it to work: fs.readFile in 'main' function returns data AFTER the callback from async.series is fired.

I get this output :

```
1 >> undefined
3 >> undefined
2 >> string
```

Though i expect :

```
1 >> undefined
2 >> string
3 >> string
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add callback to readFile

```
var main = function(callback) {
    fs.readFile('.\\html\\admin.html','utf-8',function(err,data) {
      file = data;     // 'file' is given content of admin.html
      console.log('2 >> ' + typeof file);
      callback(null);
    });  
}
```

Maybe in our case better use waterfall ?, like this

```
async.waterfall([
  function (callback) {
    fs.readFile('.\\html\\admin.html','utf-8', function (err, data) {
      callback(err, data);  
    });
  }  
], function (err, file) {
  response.end();  
})
```